# Using EJB 3 TimerService with JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.1, timer-jobs

I am writing an application to allow end-users to schedule various administrative tasks.  The server platform I'm on is JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final and EJB 3 Timers would seem to be a nearly ideal solution, except that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934464/jboss-7-1-1-and-the-ejb-3-1-timer-service), while old, indicates that 7.1.1 has an incomplete implementation with no database persistence (in spite of [this code](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/ejb/txtimer/GeneralPurposeDatabasePersistencePlugin.java.html) I saw for 4.0.2).

What do I need to do in order to implement database-persisted EJB timers in JBoss?  Do I need to upgrade JBoss or can it be done without implementing the entire framework myself?

Comment: Any particular reason you do not upgrade to JBoss 8 and decide to stick with such an outdated community release (which as you have found out are not complete or properly debugged even)? At the very least you might compile a 7.2 release yourself. Source is here: https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/tags and instructions are here: http://blog.kaltepoth.de/posts/2013/02/12/building-jboss-as7.html

Comment: My confusion is based on the fact that I distrust my interpretation of the limited, unclear and sparse documentation I can find. I have to have a very good reason to cause a production rev just for my little utility app.

Comment: Funny how our worlds differ. In mine security rules everything and not patching/upgrading, especially community editions, is severely reprimanded.

Comment: Why is DB based persistence for timers important to you? JBossAS 7.x persists timers to disk files

Comment: @Gimby - We are moving to supported EAP version with regular updates. That activity is not my activity, so it's not part of the solution for my task, which is due prior to update.

Comment: @SteveC, Partly for multi-site failover. What I'd like to have done is customize the database plugin so that I could use a table integrated into the rest of the solution.